# x86 Assembly, getting segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
msg: db "hello!", 10, 0 ;my message

section .text
extern printf ;C printf function
global main
main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    call print_string
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret ;end of program

print_string:
    pusha
    push msg
    call printf ;should print "Hello"
    popa
    ret ;return back to main
```

When I run this code I get:
hello!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Thats not the way ASM works, you have more than one error. Also your question isn't a Question. I advise you to take a look at compiled asm code with a debugger.

Comment: If this is C calling convention, the caller is reponsible for cleaning the stack. You have left `msg` pointer on there so the `ret` will fail.

Comment: I added "add esp, 4" and this fixed the code. So the problem was that I pushed the msg pointer on the stack and never popped it off? I assumed printf would pop it off.

Comment: _"I assumed printf would pop it off"_. [It does not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The print_string subroutine is modifying the stack pointer without restoring it.
The subroutine `main` has the following layout:

```
push ebp    ;save the stack frame of the caller
mov ebp, esp    ;save the stack pointer
<code for subroutine>
mov esp, ebp    ;restore the stack pointer
pop ebp    ;restore the caller's stack frame
ret ;return to address pushed onto the stack by call
```

Similarly, the print_string subroutine should have that same layout, saving the stack pointer and then restoring it before `ret`ing. Any subroutines that use the stack should save and restore the stack pointer.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
pusha
push msg
call printf ;should print "Hello"
add esp, 4
popa
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Without saving the stack pointer and restoring it, the called subroutine modifies the stackpointer, where the `call` instruction saved the return address. Consequently, when `ret` is encountered, execution jumps to the wrong return address, therefore segfaulting. Read more on [calling conventions and functions in assembly.](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html#calling)

Comment: Your answer fails to address the real problem. It introduces extra problems because many registers will get corrupted!

Comment: I merely pointed out what was causing the segmentation fault and suggested a calling convention to prevent this. If you want to address "the real problem", be my guest.

Comment: What about this `pop msg`?   In what world can you **pop an immediate value**?

Answer (score 1):

*printf* expects a pointer pushed on the stack for an argument but under C calling convention it is your task to remove this argument from the stack.

You omitted this and so the instruction `popa` puts **wrong values in all GPRS** and the instruction `ret` uses the original value of EAX as a destination address thus triggering a segmentation fault.

### Solution 1 cleaning up manually

```
print_string:
 pusha
 push  msg
 call  printf   ;should print "Hello"
 add   esp, 4   ; <-- Clean-up
 popa
 ret            ;return back to main
```

### Solution 2 using prolog/epilog on *print_string*

```
print_string:
 push  ebp
 mov   ebp, esp
 push  msg
 call  printf   ;should print "Hello"
 mov   esp, ebp ; <-- Clean-up
 pop   ebp
 ret            ;return back to main
```

Solution 2 is only possible because *printf* is a well-behaving function that preserves the EBP register. By moving EBP into ESP every extra item that was pushed between the prolog and epilog *disappears*. Solution 2 can save you from a lot of those `add esp, 4` instructions (when routines become longer).